# Acessar remotamente outra máquina unix com o Vim

Tags: terminal, vim, unix

Segundo esse vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN-GCcnI9Es é possível acessar outra máquina unix com o Vim e continuar a editar o arquivo de onde eu parei.

Como eu consigo fazer?

Comment: O ideal é usar ssh.

Comment: Assim como o Kyllopardiun disse, que eu saiba só o vim não faz isso, a não ser que exista algum plugin. O ideal é você conectar na máquina host usando algum cliente ssh e usar o vim através do tty criado pelo ssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe é:

```
vim scp://user@host//path_do_arquivo
```

Não esqueça as duas barras para declarar o path completo.

Fonte: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim

Comment: Só como complemento: se o user for e mesmo e o path puder ser reativo, simplifica para `vim scp://host/path`